# An Atlas for $\mathbb{R}/{2\pi \mathbb{Z}} $

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, geometric-topology, smooth-manifolds

I've been having some difficulty finding an atlas for $\mathbb{R}/{2\pi \mathbb{Z}}$. The way I have been thinking of this so far is by using the standard projection map $\pi$ on open intervals of length less than $2 \pi$ but I am having some trouble with details and getting stuck proving compatibility of the charts. Can somebody help me find an atlas for this quotient space? Thank you.

Comment: Can you find an atlas for $S^1$?

Comment: So ... what charts did you try to use, exactly? Provide more information about what you've tried.

Comment: I've tried to use $\pi$ restricted to $(-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2})$ and $\pi$ restricted to $(0, 2\pi)$.

Comment: Are you using the letter $\pi$ for two different things? I don't see how that could be a good idea. A chart is a pair $(U,\varphi)$ where $U\subseteq \Bbb R/2\pi\Bbb Z$ is an open set (in the quotient topology) and $\phi:U\to\Bbb R$ is a homeomorphism from $U$ onto some subset of $\Bbb R$. What are your $(U,\varphi)$s?

Comment: $\pi$ is the standard projection map. To avoid confusion I'll relabel it $f$. My charts are $(f|_{(-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2})}, f^{-1})$ and $(f|_{(0, 2\pi)}, f^{-1})$.

Comment: Not quite how I'd express that, but okay. If $x\in(0,\frac{\pi}{2})$ then clearly both charts' homeomorphisms send $x+2\pi \Bbb Z$ to $x$, so they're compatible. Where's the issue?

Comment: Oh, I see. I got tripped up a bit in the intersections of sets in the quotient space. It was a silly error. If it's not too much trouble would you mind telling me how you would express what I said earlier? I'm having some difficulty writing expressions when it comes to quotient spaces. Thank you.